# Make CJuiDatePicker field accept multiple date formats, change JS validation (yii 1.1)

Tags: jquery-ui, yii, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker with a certain date format (Y-M-D) which is the preferred and database format, but I'd like the input field associated with it to be fillable with D/M or D/M/Y as well. I.e., if the user enters 30/12 or 30/12/2013, I'd like the field to understand 2013-12-30. However, the field has some JavaScript validation going on that prevents the user to enter something other than a digit or a "-".

How can I disable the restriction that only lets the user type digits and "-"? If I could, I could either check the field onBlur and transform the user-friendly date to Y-M-D via JavaScript or just submit the value as D/M or D/M/Y and have the controller that receives the data transform it on the fly to Y-M-D before validating.

(Note: I know a solution would be to just set the date picker to D/M/Y, but I would like the user to be able to enter the date with slashes or dashes and still datepicker doesn't guess the full date when entering only day and month)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out:

The answer is the **constraintInput** setting of jQueryUI datepicker. You can set it to false.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-constrainInput

In Yii:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'date',
    //(...)
    'options' => array(
        'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd', // format of "2012-12-25"
        'constrainInput'=>false
    )
));
```